# Forming groups in R using certain row values and checking as well as removing duplicates from groups

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
PatientID   BookingID   Level1   Level2  Value 
a1           101-A1        1     HBA1C   9.4
a2           102-A2        1     LDL     116
a1           101-A1        1     VLDL    11
a1           101-A1        2     POL     10
a1           102-A1        1     HBA1c   9.4
a2           102-A2        1     VLDL    10
a1           102-A1        1     VLDL    11
a2           103-A2        1     LDL     116
a2           103-A2        1     VLDL    11
a1           102-A1        2     POL     10
```

The idea is, a patient(Unique Patient ID) can come to lab and get tested for a set of conditions - broader category of test is **level1**, and their subcategories is **level2**(level1 has one to many relationship with level2), now the **BookingId** column for a patient ID can be different attributing to different dates of visits. **value** column represents values for each test(Patient ID has one to many relationship with BookingID).

I want an output where:

```
PatientID   BookingID   Level1   Level2  Value 
a1           101-A1        1     HBA1C    9.4
a2           102-A2        1      LDL     116
a1           101-A1        1      VLDL    11
a1           101-A1        2      POL     10
a2           102-A2        1      VLDL    10
a2           103-A2        1      LDL     116
a2           103-A2        1      VLDL    11
```

We basically want to remove duplicates if for a certain - **level1** test, if a patient gets himself tested twice and the values remain same, in above example - for patient ID - a2, although has same values for a level1 test, only VLDL value(last row output - is different  from 3rd last value ) is different hence a2 remains, while seperate instances of a1 gets deleted.

Now imagine this being a very large dataset, we have to make comparisons for each level1 test and its corresponding value for a particular patient.

I tried : `final2 <- final1 %>% group_by(level1, patientId, value) %>% slice(1)`
but obviously it will not work and will remove some unnecessary rows as it does not quite perform as per logic. Please help

Comment: Booking id isn't something you need to store - and neither, I suspect, is level 1!

Comment: @Strawberry we do

Answer (score 0):

```
final <- as.data.frame(sapply(final, toupper)) # consolidate case

final[!duplicated(dplyr::select(final, -BookingID), fromLast = T),]

      PatientID BookingID Level1 Level2 Value
         A1    102-A1      1  HBA1C   9.4
         A2    102-A2      1   VLDL    10
         A1    102-A1      1   VLDL    11
         A2    103-A2      1    LDL   116
         A2    103-A2      1   VLDL    11
         A1    102-A1      2    POL    10
```

Comment: if you did not understand the problem statement correctly, we can't have row 5th in our output

Comment: whoops didn't see your case matching dilemma. thats an easy fix, see update

Comment: What does no changes mean exactly? I get a trimmed version of your  original data.frame when I execute it. Did you get an errors or warnings? Also, your example output above still has a redundant patient, test, value combination in it for A2,LDL,116 (listed twice). Do you actually want that?

Answer (score 0):

(Carefully) consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
( test_id INT NOT NULL 
, patient_id INT NOT NULL
,category_id INT NOT NULL
,value DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1,1,101,9.4),
( 2,2,102,116),
( 3,1,103, 11),
( 4,1,104, 10),
( 5,1,101,9.4),
( 6,2,105, 10),
( 7,1,105, 11),
( 8,2,106,116),
( 9,2,105, 11),
(10,1,104, 10);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
| test_id | patient_id | category_id | value  |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
|       1 |          1 |         101 |   9.40 |
|       2 |          2 |         102 | 116.00 |
|       3 |          1 |         103 |  11.00 |
|       4 |          1 |         104 |  10.00 |
|       5 |          1 |         101 |   9.40 |
|       6 |          2 |         105 |  10.00 |
|       7 |          1 |         105 |  11.00 |
|       8 |          2 |         106 | 116.00 |
|       9 |          2 |         105 |  11.00 |
|      10 |          1 |         104 |  10.00 |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(test_id) test_id FROM my_table GROUP BY patient_id,category_id,value) b 
    ON b.test_id = a.test_id 
 ORDER 
    BY test_id;
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
| test_id | patient_id | category_id | value  |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
|       2 |          2 |         102 | 116.00 |
|       3 |          1 |         103 |  11.00 |
|       5 |          1 |         101 |   9.40 |
|       6 |          2 |         105 |  10.00 |
|       7 |          1 |         105 |  11.00 |
|       8 |          2 |         106 | 116.00 |
|       9 |          2 |         105 |  11.00 |
|      10 |          1 |         104 |  10.00 |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

Incidentally, 'booking_id' can be generated on-the-fly, something like this...

```
SELECT a.test_id
     , a.patient_id
     , a.category_id
     , a.value
     , a.booking_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CONCAT_WS('-',x.patient_id,LPAD(CASE WHEN @prev = patient_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END,3,0)) booking_id
            , @prev:=patient_id 
         FROM my_table x
            , 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY patient_id
            , test_id
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY test_id;
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+------------+
| test_id | patient_id | category_id | value  | booking_id |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+------------+
|       1 |          1 |         101 |   9.40 | 1-001      |
|       2 |          2 |         102 | 116.00 | 2-001      |
|       3 |          1 |         103 |  11.00 | 1-002      |
|       4 |          1 |         104 |  10.00 | 1-003      |
|       5 |          1 |         101 |   9.40 | 1-004      |
|       6 |          2 |         105 |  10.00 | 2-002      |
|       7 |          1 |         105 |  11.00 | 1-005      |
|       8 |          2 |         106 | 116.00 | 2-003      |
|       9 |          2 |         105 |  11.00 | 2-004      |
|      10 |          1 |         104 |  10.00 | 1-006      |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------+------------+
```